# pattern matching on two arguments in ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to figure out how to match on two arguments in ocaml.

I have a function that takes in two tuples:

```
let time a b = ...;;
time (34, 4)(5, 6);; // function call
```

How can I access, say, the first item in the first tuple and add it with the first item in the second tuple? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let time (a, _) (b, _) = a + b;;
```

or, to destructure any binding outside of function arguments:

```
let time a b = 
  let a', _ = a in
  let b', _ = b in
  a' + b'
```

In general you'll find that most patterns look exactly like how you'd construct the value. Pretty handy that way.

Comment: how can I do this in the function body?

Comment: `let a', _ = a in ...`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer from @glennsl, you may find `as` useful.

```
let time (a', _ as a) (b', _ as b) = 
  (* ... *)
```

This lets you destructure both tuples, but *also* bind a name to each tuple.